# Find a linear transformation $ f: \mathbb{R} ^ {3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $ such that the unit cube becomes the parallelepiped

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Find a linear transformation $ f: \mathbb{R} ^ {3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3} $ such that the unit cube becomes the parallelepiped with vertices $(0,0,0), (2 , 0,0), (2,2,0), (0,2,0), (2,1,3), (0,1,3), (2, -1,3)$ and $(0, -1,3)$

I think the unit cube is $(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), and (0, 1, 1).$

I don't know how to do it I think I can do

$(2,1,2)=a(1,0,0)+b(0,1,0)+c(0,0,1)$ and

$(2,-1,2)=a(1,0,0)+b(0,1,0)+c(0,0,1)$

but it's absurd

Comment: Just find the three edges defining the parallelpiped and put them as the columns of a matrix.

Comment: Notice that a linear transformation $f : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is defined by how it acts on the basis vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$. You're going to have a $3 \times 3$ matrix where the columns of the matrix are going to be $f(e_1), f(e_2), f(e_3)$. Like @ElliotG said, find three defining vectors in this transformation. The rest of the edges will follow.

Comment: You are actually not looking for a linear transformation, it's an affine transformation of the form $Ax + b$. Furthermore, the unit cube has vertices $(1,1,1),(-1,1,1),(-1,-1,1),(-1,-1,-1),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(1,1,-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

The unit cube has vertices $\{(1,1,1),(-1,1,1),(-1,-1,1),(-1,-1,-1),(1,-1,-1),(1,1,-1),(1,1,-1)\}$, and the transformation in question may be an affine transformation in general:
$$
f(x) = Ax + b,
$$
or more compactly:
$$
f(x) = \begin{pmatrix}A&b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Lets first pick 4 linearly independent vertices from the unit cube and stack them in a matrix including an additional row of ones to account for $b$, say:
$$
X = \begin{pmatrix}-1&-1&-1&1\\-1&-1&1&1\\-1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Now, pick 4 affinely independent vertices from the output parallelepiped, and stack them in a matrix $V$, say:
$$
V = \begin{pmatrix}2&2&2&0\\0&2&1&1\\0&0&3&3\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Then, you can solve for $A$ and $b$ as:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}A & b\end{pmatrix} = VX^{-1},
$$
which gives:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 
         0    &     0 &  -1  \\
         1 & -0.5 & 0 \\ 
         0 & 1.5 & 0\end{pmatrix},\qquad b = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0.5 \\ 1.5\end{pmatrix}.
$$

EDIT: Actually, in your case it turns out that $f$ is indeed linear, and the vertices that you have are outputs of $f$ on the unit cube according to your definition. So, finding the columns of $A$ indeed amounts to stacking all of the vertices horizontally in a matrix $V$ and performing Gaussian elimination. The columns of $A$ are the columns of $V$ which become standard basis vectors after elimination. However, the approach above is more general.

Comment: I'm not sure why you insist that the unit cube is $[-1,1]^3$ and not $[0,1]^3$. Shouldn't the unit cube be constructed from the *unit interval* $[0,1]$ and have *unit volume* $1$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Actually, I've seen both definitions used, but $[-1,1]^3$ comes from the infinity norm unit ball $\{ x\in\mathbb{R}^3 | \lVert x \rVert_\infty \leq 1\}$.